# Permission Error when trying to use panda.read.excel in python

Tags: python, pandas

As I said in the title, I am having a weird error when using this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
data = pd.read_excel("[file directions]")
print(data.head())
```

I get the error message: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:"

is there some fix to this or do I need to use other files than excel files?

Comment: By chance do you have the file open in Excel? It might work if you close it in Excel first.

Comment: oh bruh. Yeah I was just stupid... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happens when the file is used by another program. Check if you have the file opened with Microsoft Excel or if the file is used by another service.